# Select table column names as values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a SQL table with an arbitrary number of records (X) and an arbitrary number of columns (Y)

| RecordID | Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | ... | Column Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value11 | Value12 | Value13 | ... | Value1Y |
| 2 | Value21 | Value22 | Value23 | ... | Value2Y |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| X | ValueX1 | ValueX2 | ValueX3 | ... | ValueXY |

Is it possible to construct a query that reduces the data to a simple three-column lookup of ID, column name and value, as follows :

| RecordID | ColumnName | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Column1 | Value11 |
| 1 | Column2 | Value12 |
| 1 | Column3 | Value13 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | ColumnY | Value1Y |
| 2 | Column1 | Value21 |
| 2 | Column2 | Value22 |
| 2 | Column3 | Value23 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | ColumnY | Value2Y |
| ... | ... | ... |
| X | Column1 | ValueX1 |
| X | Column2 | ValueX2 |
| X | Column3 | ValueX3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| X | ColumnY | ValueXY |

Conservation of the data type is obviously not a concern, a simple text representation on each case would be sufficient?

(I'm sure this is answered elsewhere but I don't know what this would be "called" so I'm having trouble finding out how to achieve it...)

Comment: This is called "unpivoting" a search of this will give you a wealth of solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNPIVOT is more performant, but here is an option that will dynamically unpivot your data without actually using dynamic SQL, and you don't have to specify all the columns nor worry about datatypes/conversions.

```
Select A.RecordID
      ,B.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select [Key]
                       ,Value
                 From OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('RecordID','OtherColumns','ToExclude')
              ) B
```

Comment: Thanks @John, I came across one of your previous answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747723/unpivoting-with-column-headers-single-row after reading Larnu's original comment, is there any reason or otherwise to choose one over the other?

Comment: @AlanO'Brien This answer has the benefit that it works dynamically (sort of, because in a view or stored procedure you still need `sp_refreshsqlmodule` if there are changes to the base table design). But it's going to be much much slower than unpivoting using either `UNPIVOT` or `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @AlanO'Brien Performance over Flexibility.   You need to decide which is more important.   That said, you may be surprised with the performance of my approach.