# Dynamically Transpose 1 Row of Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, transpose

- I have an existing table called **Users**, in a SQL Server Database
- I wish to be able to generate a table that shows all the Column Headings in the Column 1, and 1 row of sample data in Column 2. Perhaps the Last row?
- I need the query to be dynamic, so I can change the table name and capture all **COLUMN_NAMES** without having to hard-code them

|  | Table: Users |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | UserID | User_Name | Country | Employed |
| 1 | E24141 | Elon Mosk | US | Y |
| 2 | E24142 | Bill Jates | US | N |
| 3 | E24142 | Jeff Lezos | US | N |

| Query1: Get List of Columns |  |
| --- | --- |
| COLUMN_NAME | SAMPLE |
| UserID | E24142 |
| User_Name | Jeff Lezos |
| Country | US |
| Employed | N |

So far I have figured out how to create column 1, to get a list of Column Names as Rows.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM ENT_Layer.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Users' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%'
```

However, I can't find a way to add COLUMN 2, which is the 'Sample data'. I have read about PIVOT & UNPIVOT but I'm not sure that is what I need to do. I suspect I need to dynamically be able to select a names list of Column Names, which i can achieve with the code below, but am unsure of the next step.

Any advice?

```
DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns =
    COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM ENT_Layer.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Users' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%'
) AS B

Print @Columns
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73691009/select-table-column-names-as-values/73691087#73691087

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On second read, if you are looking for just ONE SAMPLE row

```
Select B.* 
 From  (Select top 1 * from AnyTableOrQuery Order by SomeCol Desc) A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select [Key]
                       ,Value
                 From OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES )  ) 
              ) B
```

The `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` is optional

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. I have tried integrating your code but get the following error: Invalid object name 'OpenJson'. I am using SQL Server Management Studio (2016). Turns out my compatibility level is 110! So I might not be able to use JSON?

Comment: @Calico Select @@version  This will give you an actual version.  If <2016 there is an XML approach as well

Comment: Thanks. The version returns:  'Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU29) (KB5010786) - 14.0.3436.1 (X64)   Mar 18 2022 13:21:03   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)'. From what i was reading online, compatibility versions < 130 don't allow the use of JSON

Comment: @Calico  You should be good to go   https://dbfiddle.uk/fnFfUF_S

Comment: I had to run a statement ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130. After that the code worked great!  However, ROW 1 is a default row (with default data). Is there a means to pick the last row?

Comment: @Calico   In this example, I used Order by ID Desc  https://dbfiddle.uk/QjACpfM1