# Show column name along with column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2019

I have a following table:

```
declare @tab1 table(
    Id int identity,
    address1 varchar(100),
    city varchar(50),
    name varchar(50),
    phone varchar(10)
)

insert into @tab1 (address1, city, name, phone) values
    ('C-10', 'UX', 'A', '9898989898'),
    ('A-19', 'DX', 'B', '8888888888')

select * from @tab1
```

I want the output as column name along with column value based on id. Like below.

This script is my desired output

```
declare @tab2 table(
    item varchar(100),
    value varchar(200)
)

insert into @tab2 (item, value) values
    ('Address1', 'C-10'),
    ('city', 'UX'),
    ('name', 'A'),
    ('phone', '9898989898')

select * from @tab2
```

I'm unable to write this query that shows column name along with its column value.

Comment: This usually is not a task for database query, but for presentation layer. You can get values and column names if you create json (`select * from @tab1 for json auto`) - but all this depends on what you actually need.

Comment: I want column name adjacent to their column values

Comment: What is wrong with `select * from @tab2` ,the statement that you gave in the question  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/m3YP9D7I ) ?

Comment: @Luuk The expected output is shown in the second query result.

Comment: @SelVazi that's not output, that's a script. The question may be asking two completely different things. Does it ask how to create a script but this an "output" ? Or is it trying to UNPIVOT data but shows a script instead of the desired output?

Comment: If the question is how to convert columns to rows, that's possible using the [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16#unpivot-example) operator, or CROSS APPLY as the answer shows. If the question is how to create an `INSERT` script with attribute/value pairs, the UNPIVOT operation can be used to extract the strings that would go in the row constructors

Comment: @RahulAggarwal The CROSS APPLY listed below (+1) is a nudge more performant than this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73691009/select-table-column-names-as-values/73691087#73691087  But with my approach, you don't have to specify the columns nor worry about converting datatypes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `CROSS APPLY` and row-value-constructor:

```
SELECT t.id, ca.*
FROM @tab1 AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('address1', t.address1),
    ('city',     t.city),
    ('name',     t.name),
    ('phone',    t.phone)
) AS ca(col_name, col_val)
```

The query assumes that the data-type of all columns is compatible.